# Best alternate sentence for 'Please let me know if any questions/comments'

Tags: creative-writing, technical-writing, email

I feel bored to have this in my all mails 'Please let me know if any questions/comments', any best alternate sentence would be helpful for me

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE. As a rule, avoid asking "what to write".

Comment: Oops sorry, as I am new I don't know the rule and thanks for letting me know

Comment: It's OK. The reason is, we are just people with lives, and Google is your friend. If you want a more thoughtful answer than what Google can provide, the try editing your question to be both helpful to you and to other people as well. identify what it is in your question that could be broadly useful information, and ask about that.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! To learn more about the site and its scope please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @Amadeus' answer or one of the following:

- "Any questions or comments are welcome"
- "Feel free to leave questions or comments"
- "Questions or comments are appreciated"

If your standard email encourages an ongoing dialogue, you can add 'further' to the line:

- "If further questions should arise, do feel free to ask."

There are many ways to say it. Say whatever you feel best suits

Answer (score 1):

Since Questions/Comments covers every possible response, perhaps

"Please feel free to respond."

Or

"I welcome any feedback."